# ffmpeg images and audio to video

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have several images(slides) and several audio files that I would like to combine, using C#,AForge and ffmpeg, or any thing else you might suggest.
There are several audio files, each reads the text in one single image.

The images divide into two groups - images with a corresponding audio file and images without a corresponding audio file.

1. Images without an audio should be shown for some predefined time(for
   example 4 seconds).
2. Images with an audio should be shown, with the audio starting when they
   appear, for as long as the corresponding audio plays.

The logic and mechanism is very simple, but I do not know how to implement it.
What classes or objects will I use?
Do I need to paint every frame between two images?

Note:The images represent slides, a PowerPoint presentation whose every slide was saved as a jpeg picture.

EDIT: Example
Let's say I have 5 images, two of them have a corresponding audio file, hence two audio files.

Image 1 is shown for 4 seconds.

Image 2 appears and audio 1 plays, audio stops and image 2 disappears.

Image 3 is shown for 4 seconds.

Image 4 is shown for 4 seconds.

Image 5 appears and audio 2 plays, audio stops and image 5 disappears.

Comment: I assume all of the images will share the same properties, but will the audio files also be similar, or will they vary in channel layout, sample rate, sample format, etc? Also, it will be informative if you show some details about your typical inputs and your `ffmpeg` info. Please show the complete output of: `ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i audio.foo`

Comment: I do no understand most of what you say unfortunately(I am new to this).
The audio files will be mp3, or wav, all the same and created in a similar fashion(all those details you talked about should hence be the same).
My input is several similar Jpeg images and a several similar audio files(in varying lengths, although short).

Comment: This perhaps: Input #1, mp3, from 'audio.mp3':
  Duration: 00:01:02.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s

Comment: Of course:http://pastebin.com/gEjjCfS9

Comment: Thanks. Oddly the images have `.jpg` suffix, but `ffmpeg` says they are PNG.

Comment: Indeed, although the image is for sure a jpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Concatenating

You can use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). Using the parameters you supplied in your example:

```
ffmpeg \
-f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 \
-loop 1 -t 4 -i 01.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 3 -i 02.jpg \
-i 02.wav \
-loop 1 -t 4 -i 03.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 4 -i 04.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 6 -i 05.jpg \
-i 05.wav \
-filter_complex \
"[1:0][0:0][2:0][3:0][4:0][0:0][5:0][0:0][6:0][7:0]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[vv][a]; \
 [vv]format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

## Getting duration

You can get the duration for each audio input using `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 02.wav
```

The resulting output can be used as a variable for the appropriate `-t` in the `ffmpeg` command.

### Notes

- In this example `02.wav` is 3 seconds long, so `-t 3` is used for `02.jpg` to set a 3 second duration, and `05.wav` is 6 seconds long, so `-t 6` is used for `05.jpg`.
- You didn't mention a desired output format, so I chose H.264 video and AAC audio in MP4 container. If this is not what you want then remove `-movflags +faststart`, remove the format filter, and rename the video map.
- [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) generates the silent audio. Its duration only needs to be shorter than your shortest audio input: the concat filter will automatically pad the rest to match the corresponding video segment. You can adjust `channel_layout` and `sample_rate` to match your audio inputs if desired. Be aware that if they are different, then the concat filter will automatically choose a common sample rate, sample format, and channel layout, so if the output is different than expected then that is why.
- Alternatively, you could use stream specifiers to name your inputs to the concat filter. I usually do but in a scripted command it may make less sense. Anyway, in this case it would be:

  ```
  [1:v][0:a][2:v][3:a][4:v][0:a][5:v][0:a][6:v][7:a]
  ```
- Adapting these examples to work in your favorite scripting language is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the swift and helpful answer.
Unfortunately my question was not clear enough, I will edit it.
Sorry for the trouble and thanks again.

Comment: @user5830891 I changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I tried making this work and yet I have a certain problem that I couldn't solve.
pastebin.com/reVYwJqf
It gives out the error:
Unable to find a suitable output format for '\'\: Invalid argument.

Comment: @user5830891 You need to show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: Sure, pastebin.com/i6XzURyE. Thanks

Comment: @user5830891 Change `[a]" \ [vv] format=yuv420p [v]` to `[a];[vv] format=yuv420p [v]"` and get rid of the backslashes.

Comment: Everything works, thank you very much for all the assistance with this, professional, swift kind and helpful.

Comment: Where can I find documentation on the format of the first part of `--filter_complex` argument which goes like `"[1:0][0:0][2:0]...`?